# Unable to transform between frames for which transform exists

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Loading objects in the planning scene with `moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface::addCollisionObjects` results in error `Unable to transform from frame 'world' to frame '/panda_link0'. Returning identity.`.

- I tracked down the issue to [moveit::core::getTransform](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/68eb44ded1ca665dfab81fc5c615a81f95409291/moveit_core/transforms/src/transforms.cpp#L89) which gets called by the interface which calls methods from `planning_scene`, [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/68eb44ded1ca665dfab81fc5c615a81f95409291/moveit_core/planning_scene/src/planning_scene.cpp#L82).
- At the same time, I'm 100% sure the transform exists before publishing the objects, because 1) prior to adding the object I sleep and spin until the transform is available; 2) I can see it if I `rosrun tf2_tools view_frames.py`.
- I tried to update moveit's internal map of transforms using `planning_scene_monitor::PlanningSceneMonitor::updateFrameTransforms()`, and checking the last update was recent with `getLastUpdateTime` (it is 0.2s - 0.25s ago); [This issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/323) discusses the same procedure.
- Restarting my node (only) doesn't display the error at all, so it really seems an "update" issue.

More details on what I might be doing wrong:

- I'm sending a collision object with `collision_object.header.frame_id = my_object.getPose().header.frame_id;` which is initialized elsewhere to be the string "world";
- I'm publishing the equivalent of writing this transform:

```
auto static_transform_stamped = geometry_msgs::TransformStamped {};
static_transform_stamped.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
static_transform_stamped.header.frame_id = "world";
static_transform_stamped.child_frame_id = "panda_link0";
static_transform_stamped.transform.translation.x = 0.0;
static_transform_stamped.transform.translation.y = 0.0;
static_transform_stamped.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
static_transform_stamped.transform.rotation.w = 1.0;
static_transform_stamped.transform.rotation.x = 0.0;
static_transform_stamped.transform.rotation.y = 0.0;
static_transform_stamped.transform.rotation.z = 0.0;
```

on a topic and sending it (after aggregation happens) in a separate node (as per #[310440](https://answers.ros.org/question/310440/how-do-i-broadcast-multiple-static-transforms-from-different-objects-in-the-same-process/)) but, as I said previously, I'm also sleeping and spinning until said transform is live before even attempting to add objects to the collision scene.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310862/unable-to-transform-between-frames-for-which-transform-exists/) by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 589 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I couldn't find a fix to the error, I ended up switching to `moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface::applyCollisionObjects` which seems to mostly work without errors so far.

---

Originally posted by [aPonza](https://answers.ros.org/users/37353/aponza/) with karma: 589 on 2019-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cpetersmeier](https://answers.ros.org/users/43529/cpetersmeier/) on 2019-07-09**:
I have the same error when trying to place workpieces in a `UF_PALETTE` Frame in Rviz. One way to may overcome this would be to write a listener which looks up the transform and add the offsets manually in your main program where you are adding the object.

Thats a little tedious though in my opinion.